# Apply RegEx Only to Words that have length > 2

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a RegEx expression that replaces entire word with *** IF they contain a digit, but only IF the word is more than 2 characters. For example,

The boy cried w0lf aga1n for 2 days in row! 12 12345

Would read as

The boy cried **** ***** for 2 days in a row! 12 *****

For finding words with a digit, the following expression seems to work:

```
[a-z]*\d+[a-z]*
```

But I would like a solution that only finds words with greater with length greater than 2.

Comment: I think it easier to check the length of the words that you've matched.

Answer (score 0):

Use callback function for [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and check for length of word:

```js
var str = 'The boy cried w0lf aga1n for 2 days in row! 12 12345';
var r = /[a-z]*\d+[a-z]*/g;

var replacedStr = str.replace(r, function(v){
  return v.length <= 2 ? v : '*'.repeat(v.length);
});

console.log(replacedStr);
```

**Edit**: in case replacement is always string **'***'** (based on [Jan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48386054/555121)):

```js
var str = 'The boy cried w0lf aga1n for 2 days in row! 12 12345';
var r = /\b(?=\w*\d)\w{3,}\b/g;

var replacedStr = str.replace(r, '***');

console.log(replacedStr);
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to do this in one RegEx expression?

Comment: If your replacement was string of fixed length, say 3 asterisks '***' for any word, that would be possible, but as your replacement depends on matched word, it's not

Comment: I can relax that requirement - we can go with 3 asterisks

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
\b(?=[^\d\W]*?\d)\w{3,}\b
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/QGaKNL/1/).

---

Broken down, this says

```
\b               # a word boundary
(?=[^\d\W]*?\d)  # a pos. lookahead, making sure there's a digit in the word
\w{3,}           # at least three word characters
\b               # another word boundary
```

---

You can replace this with a fixed pattern (i.e. `***`) but you'll need a function for the string length.